# How to copy a whole row as a template and replace one columns value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet which im using to build product data. I need to handle some custom SKU's and id like to have them stored in a string like "XYZ,ABC,FGH" in an alternate sheet.

The generic products are generated in the other sheet for various sizes automatically. I would like on the end of this list to be able to take one of these automatic rows as a template and replace the SKU with one of the custom SKU's if they exist in the other config sheet.

So for example:

```
SKU'S | Name | Width | Height | Weight | Quantity 
--------------------------------------------------
PARENT| X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 0
M1    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 1
M2    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 2
M3    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 3
M4    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 4
M5    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 5
```

Then append:

```
ABC    | X
XYZ    | X
FGH    | X
```

Keeping the existing columns the other products use.

The X's are just a representation for the other columns I want to copy (ive added some further columns as example data). The only thing I want to change is the SKU. Its a duplicate apart from the SKU (which I want to replace) and the Quantity. The consistent one to copy and use as the template would be the row with PARENT as the SKU.

The result is to just be a new row underneath M5 row. These are additional rows to just be tagged onto the end except for a change in the SKU.

The import is a lot of duplication to the database which is the product attributes like width, height, depth, weight, etc. This is set in a sheet I made with the name VARS. So I would create a simple field in VARS for 'Custom Additional SKUs' in say VARS!$B$10 with the value 'ABC,XYZ,FGH'. These would then use the same columns as the SKU's in say a sheet called INVENTORY.

The end result would be something like:

```
SKU'S | Name | Width | Height | Weight | Quantity 
--------------------------------------------------
PARENT| X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 0
M1    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 1
M2    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 2
M3    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 3
M4    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 4
M5    | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 5
ABC   | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 0
XYZ   | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 0
FGH   | X    | 10    | 20     | 100    | 0
```

**Final solution based on feedback to help others.**

Based on the great input from pnuts I went with the following in column A underneath:

```
=sort(transpose(split(VARS!A1,",")),1,TRUE)
```

In column B:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A7),"",QUERY(SKU!A2:F2,"select B,C,D,E,F",0))
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
=sort(transpose(split(NamedRange1,",")),1,TRUE)
```

and next to the above something like:

```
=QUERY(SKU!A:F,"select B,C,D,E,F where A='PARENT'",0)
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it very well. I have updated the question with more detail and example data.